# how to get value from table td using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to get the value of **Save** using jquery through input on keyup function.. i am matching value with **Buy**..means if value matched with the value(range) of **Buy**..then get the value of **Save**..
for example if i entered 3 in textfield then it gets value from **Save** 45%..and if i entered 8 then result should be 51%..entered 15 result 56% and so on. 
here is image link for better understanding.

http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/807/3129634990.jpg

```
<table class="attribute_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Buy</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Price/unit</th>
        <th class="save_red">Save</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3-5</td>
        <td>Pairs</td>
        <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$4.99</span></td>
        <td class="save_red">45%</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6-11</td>
        <td>Pairs</td>
        <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$4.49</span></td>
        <td class="save_red">51%</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12-23</td>
        <td>Pairs</td>
        <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$3.99</span></td>
        <td class="save_red">56%</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>24+</td>
        <td>Pairs</td>
        <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$3.90</span></td>
        <td class="save_red">57%</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

here is input field

```
<label for="">Enter Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"></input>
```

i have tried some code but still no luck..

Comment: What is your most promising code?

Comment: Can you post a snapshot on your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding data attributes holding the price limits on each `td` contains the price limits:

```js
$(document).on('input', '#qty', function() {
  var that = $(this);
  var val = that.val();
  if (!isNaN(val)) {
    $('.limitTd').each(function() {      
      var thatTd = $(this);
      //var from = parseInt(thatTd.attr('data-from'));
      //var to = parseInt(thatTd.attr('data-to'));
      var lim = thatTd.html().toString().split('-'); 
      if (lim.indexOf('-') != -1) {
        var from = parseInt(lim[0]);
        var to = parseInt(lim[1]);
      } else {
        var from = parseInt(lim.toString().replace('+'));
        var to = 9999999;
      }   
      console.log(lim);
      if ((val >= from) && (val <= to)) {  
        var save = thatTd.closest('tr').find('.save_red').html();
        $('#saveDiv').html(save);            
      }           
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="attribute_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Buy</th>
        <th>Unit</th>
        <th>Price/unit</th>
        <th class="save_red">Save</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="limitTd" data-from="3" data-to="5">3-5</td>
        <td>Pairs</td>
        <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$4.99</span></td>
        <td class="save_red">45%</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="limitTd" data-from="6" data-to="11">6-11</td>
        <td>Pairs</td>
        <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$4.49</span></td>
        <td class="save_red">51%</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="limitTd" data-from="12" data-to="23">12-23</td>
        <td>Pairs</td>
        <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$3.99</span></td>
        <td class="save_red">56%</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="limitTd" data-from="24" data-to="99999">24+</td>
        <td>Pairs</td>
        <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$3.90</span></td>
        <td class="save_red">57%</td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
<label for="">Enter Quantity</label>
  <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty"></input>

<div id="saveDiv" style="border:1px solid #d8d8d8;width: 100px;height:50px;float:left"></div>
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE (No data attributes)**

If you don't want to use data attributes, you must manipulate the html to extract the price limits.

For example:

```
var lim = $('.limitTd').html().split('-');
var from = lim[0];
var to = lim[1];
```

Comment: Thanks..its working..but i don't want to use data-from and data-to..any alternative for that..??

Comment: Updated as you do not have to use data-attributes

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var mapUnits = [];
 $('tr').each(function(i) {
   if (!$(this).find("td:nth-child(1)")[0]) {
     return;
   }
   var units = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1)")[0].innerText;
   var saveperc = $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)")[0].innerText;
   var splits = units.split('-');

   var range1 = parseInt(splits[0]);
   var range2 = parseInt(splits[1] ? splits[1] : 10000);
   mapUnits.push({
     range1: range1,
     range2: range2,
     saveperc: saveperc
   })

 });

 $("#qty").keyup(function() {
   $('#saveperc').html('');
   var val = $("#qty").val();
   for (var m in mapUnits) {
     if (mapUnits[m].range1 <= val && mapUnits[m].range2 >= val) {
       $('#saveperc').html(mapUnits[m].saveperc);
     }
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="attribute_table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Buy</th>
      <th>Unit</th>
      <th>Price/unit</th>
      <th class="save_red">Save</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3-5</td>
      <td>Pairs</td>
      <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$4.99</span>
      </td>
      <td class="save_red">45%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6-11</td>
      <td>Pairs</td>
      <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$4.49</span>
      </td>
      <td class="save_red">51%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>12-23</td>
      <td>Pairs</td>
      <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$3.99</span>
      </td>
      <td class="save_red">56%</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>24+</td>
      <td>Pairs</td>
      <td class="td_price"><span class="price">$3.90</span>
      </td>
      <td class="save_red">57%</td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<label for="">Enter Quantity</label>
<input type="number" name="qty" id="qty"></input>
<div id='saveperc'></div>
```

If you cant change the Html, do like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$('#qty').on('keyup', function() {
    var trs = $('table.attribute_table').find('tr:not(:first)');
    var val = trs.find('td:first').text();
    values = val.split('-');
    if ($(this).val() >= values[0] && $(this).val() <= values[1]) {
        var dis = trs.find('td.save_red').text();
        alert(dis);
    }
})
```